# How does direct data access with a NpyIter (new API) work? How do I deal with the char * type?

Tags: c, numpy, scipy

I'm throwing up my hands here and hoping that someone here will know enough about the new NpyIter API in Numpy's C API to quickly let me know what I'm doing wrong.

I have an array of shape ( really big, somewhat big ). The elements are doubles >= 0. For every row, I need to find the sum of the contiguous nonzero values that sum to the largest value. I don't know of any way to do this quickly in Python alone (really big is ~1e5 at times), so I've been using Weave instead.

In my old code, I had the following:

```
            double *p1,*res;
            double g,d,q;
            PyArrayIterObject *itr;
            int axis = 1;
            g = 0;
            d = 0;
            itr = (PyArrayIterObject *) PyArray_IterAllButAxis(py_x,&axis);
            while(PyArray_ITER_NOTDONE(itr)) {
                const int go = x_array->strides[axis]/sizeof(double);
                p1 = (double *) PyArray_ITER_DATA(itr);
                res = (double *) PyArray_GETPTR1(py_r,itr->index);
                g = 0;
                d = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < x_array->dimensions[axis]; i++) {
                    d+=*p1;
                    if (d>g) g=d;
                    if ((*p1)==0) d=0;
                    p1+=go;
                }
                *res = g;
                PyArray_ITER_NEXT(itr);
            }
            PyArray_free(itr);
```

This works, but it leaks memory terribly. I'm not sure how to stop it from leaking, and the documentation for the old PyArrayIter is rather lacking in terms of memory management.

I've tried to write new code with the NpyIter API, but the documentation for that in things *other* than memory management is lacking. Specifically, I'm not at all sure how I'm supposed to get access to the actual array values. I've tried the following:

```
            char *p1; 
            double *res;
            char **p1p;
            double g,d,q;
            int go;
            NpyIter* iter;
            NpyIter_IterNextFunc *iternext;
            g = 0;
            d = 0;
            iter = NpyIter_New(x_array, NPY_ITER_READONLY|NPY_ITER_EXTERNAL_LOOP, NPY_KEEPORDER, NPY_NO_CASTING, NULL);
            iternext = NpyIter_GetIterNext(iter, NULL);
            p1p = NpyIter_GetDataPtrArray(iter);

            do {
                p1 = *p1p;
                const int go = x_array->strides[1]/sizeof(double);
                res = (double *) PyArray_GETPTR1(py_r,NpyIter_GetIterIndex(iter));
                g = 0;
                d = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < x_array->dimensions[1]; i++) {
                    d+= p1;
                    if (d>g) g=d;
                    if ((*p1)==0) d=0;
                    p1+=go;
                }
                *res = g;
            } while(iternext(iter));

            NpyIter_Deallocate(iter);
```

However, this obviously doesn't work because of char * vs. double *. I'm not sure, however, how to take the (char **) returned from NpyIter_GetDataPtrArray and turn it into actual array values: the documentation extremely unhelpfully instead uses a function that isn't given and takes a char *.

How can I do this in a way that works and doesn't leak memory?

Comment: I've never used the NPyIter api, but is there a reason why you can't just access the memory directly? I've had lots of joy using ctypes with numpy arrays. Its normally just a block of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, you need to follow the usual PyObject memory management rules: `Py_DECREF` your `PyArrayIterObject` after use to avoid leaking memory. (`PyArray_free` does something quite different.)

For `NpyIter`:

To get access to the data, grab `(double*)(*dataptr)`.

If you don't exactly know what you are doing, don't use `NPY_ITER_EXTERNAL_LOOP`. To replicate the behavior of `IterAllButAxis`, you need to call `NpyIter_RemoveAxis` to remove the axis you don't want to iterate over from the iteration.